# Dynamic Add/Remove Class Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, addclass

I am creating an autosuggest box that has a  of suggestion returned to it, and I am trying to add/remove the class "searchsuggestinnerulhighlight" to individual links. Here is the dynamically returned  ta

```
    <DIV id="searchsuggestinner">
    <UL id=searchsuggestinnerul>
    <LI>
    <A href="#" id="1" class = "hoverme" onMouseDown="searchsuggestSubmit('appalachian trail');">appalachian trail</A>
   </LI>
   </UL>
   </DIV>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
 $(".hoverme").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
    if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
       $("#" + mocount).removeClass("searchsuggestinnerulhighlight");
       mocount = $(this).attr('id');
       $("#" + mocount).addClass("searchsuggestinnerulhighlight");
    } else {
       $("#" + mocount).removeClass("searchsuggestinnerulhighlight");
    }
 });
```

Originally I had .css("background-color"... and now I've changed it to add class and remove class and it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
$("#" + mocount).add("searchsuggestinnerulhighlight");
```

To:

```
$("#" + mocount).addClass("searchsuggestinnerulhighlight");
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my part. I've changed it to that and it is still not working. Any other suggestions? I think it has to do with how the returned is not actually on the page to start with..

Comment: I would look at what @lonesomeday posted, he makes some good points. The fact that you are using an integer for your id is not kosher except in HTML5, this could be causing issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
mocount = $(this).attr('id');
$("#" + mocount)
```

That's seriously dodgy jQuery!

First, you don't need `attr` to get the `id`.  You can get it with `this.id`. This is far, far quicker.

Second, you don't need to get the `id` to get a jQuery selection containing the clicked element.  Just use `$(this)` instead.

Finally, as Gabe has said, use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) rather than `add`. So, all in all:

```
$(this).addClass('searchsuggestinnerulhighlight');
```

One other thing, though -- using a ID value starting with a number was not allowed in HTML before HTML5.  Its behaviour is not guaranteed.

Comment: add was a typo, I had addClass before. Sorry. Any other ideas why it wouldn't work then?

Comment: @Adam What "doesn't work"? Do you get any errors? Have you made the other changes I recommended?

Comment: The class is not added because the background does not highlight. I made the "this.id" change, and then alerted the id to make sure it was working but it said "undefined" instead of the value, and then when I changed it back to ".attr('id')" it worked. I did use $(this) instead of the id, however, and that is working fine. It is overall still not adding the class though
 
here is a link to it: 184.106.227.117/~srchulo/searchsuggest/test.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in a comment, but I can't. Implement lonesomeday's changes, but when he uses $(this).id, try just using this.id as 'this' should already be a jquery object. (We don't want $($(this)).)